# How do we modularize files and then use in firebase cloud functions when using expressjs

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am using express in firebase cloud functions.
So my index.js needs to be moularized and split into different files.
What is the best way to do it.

I know that there is a SO post to how we can modularize nodejs apps, i just want to know how we could do the same if we use express.

`test.js`

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
      res.json(200, {'test': 'it works!'});
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

`index.js`

```
var test = require("./routes/test.js");
var other = require("./routes/other.js");
...
//all your code for creating app 
...
app.use('/test', test);
app.use('/other', other);
```

can we do something like this in firebase cloud functions when using with nodejs

and then export them like below:

`exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

Or is there any correct way to do it in case of express.

Thanks

Comment: Cloud Functions is not going to behave any differently than normal node programs with respect to modularization.  If your code is not working the way you expect, please edit the question to show any error messages that you're getting.

Comment: so what you meant is i could use the files just like the same as above?

Comment: Yes, I think you should just give it a try, then ask a question if something doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: This is working, with no issues

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) link, you could add a express app in firebase.
And in order to modularize the app into different files and then manage seperately,

you do like below.

**index.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const homePageRoute = require('./homePageRoute');
    const cors = require('cors')({
        origin: true
    });
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors);
    app.use('/api/home', homePageRoute);
    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and in your homePageRoute file you do like below

**homePageRoute.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/some-route', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    // code
});

module.exports = router;
```

This will help.